# Is there a way to stream screen to localhost?

Tags: server, ffmpeg, lan, streaming, smart-tv

I want to stream my desktop to `Sony Bravia Tv` in local area network.

There is no Linux way to stream desktop to smart tv on LAN.

However I found a workaround, If there is a stream on localhost like 
`http://localhost:9000` I  can play it on tv via `vGet Cast` chrome extension by copying link into it, but it only supports `http` not `rtmp` or `udp`

I found the command below, it runs okay but it is `tcp://0.0.0.0:9000` so I can not send it to Tv.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i :0.0 -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 1 -threads  -f mpegts - | nc -l -p 8090
```

I tried this

```
 ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -framerate 30 -video_size 600x400 -i :0.0+0,0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 3000k -vf "scale=1280:-1,format=yuv420p" -g 60 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv "http://localhost:8090/live"
```

but this time I get the following error:

```
 Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed: Connection refused
 http://localhost:8090/live: Connection refused
```

Comment: Based on your rating, I feel silly to ask but is the port forwarded? (Sometimes we miss the simple things)

Comment: @EODCraftStaff thank you for responding. What do you mean by port forwarding? That port is not in use.

Comment: Here is one possible solution: [Is it possible to forward NON-http connecting request to some other port in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35521557/6543935)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand Local Network but does not the port need to be allowed (forwarded) in the router or is this not necessary on a local network? (See router security settings)

Comment: @EODCraftStaff  yes, there is a setting in the router but I already enabled router to reach Tv. So my problem has nothing to do with router.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to stream to `localhost` via VLC tool `cvlc`.

I just concocted it, maybe someone improves it or posts a different approach.

```
 cvlc screen:// :screen-fps=10 :scre-caching=100 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,acodec=mpga,ab=256,scale=1,width=1280,height=800}:http{dst=0.0.0.0:1234,access=http,mux=ts}'
```

EDIT: I am sorry, though it answers my question, I tested it on `gmediarender`, it worked, but I just tested it on Tv, it won't work on `Sony Bravia Tv`. Maybe it's a video format issue or missing `seek table` in the video format which is stated [here](http://realmike.org/blog/2011/02/09/live-desktop-streaming-via-dlna-on-gnulinux/)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `ffserver` a web server from `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg` itself you simply can do it.

#### first ...

Config the `ffserver` which mostly is at `/etc/ffmpeg`, if it was not there, do this:

```
 dpkg -L ffmpeg | grep server.conf
```

and here is a simple configuration (mine) for `webm` format:

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 40000
CustomLog -

UseDefaults

<Feed screen.ffm>               # This is the input feed where FFmpeg will send
   File screen.ffm            # video stream.
   FileMaxSize 1G              # Maximum file size for buffering video
   ACL allow 127.0.0.1
   ACL allow localhost
</Feed>

<Stream screen>              # Output stream URL definition
   Feed screen.ffm              # Feed from which to receive video
   Format webm

   # Audio settings
   AudioCodec vorbis
   AudioBitRate 64             # Audio bitrate

   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libvpx
   
   VideoSize 1600x800           # Video resolution
   # VideoSize 320x240           # Video resolution
   VideoFrameRate 15           # Video FPS

   AVOptionVideo cpu-used 10
   AVOptionVideo qmin 10
   AVOptionVideo qmax 42
   AVOptionVideo quality good
   AVOptionAudio flags +global_header
   PreRoll 15
   StartSendOnKey
   VideoBitRate 400            # Video bitrate
</Stream>


<Stream status.html>            # Server status URL
   Format status
   # Only allow local people to get the status
   ACL allow 192.168.1.0 192.168.1.255
</Stream>
```

If you open the original config file, you will see it has a lot of comments, `mv` that to other name and paste mine in place of `ffserver.conf'. Then run the command:

```
ffserver
```

After starting the server, it will listen for stream from `ffmpeg` on port `8090` while the feed to the server we named it **screen.ffm**.

#### Second ...

Then you can run any valid `ffmepg` command to send stream to the `ffserver`. Here is mine:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1600x800 -i :0.0 -c:v libvpx -f alsa -i pulse http://127.0.0.1:8090/screen.ffm
```

screenshot of running `ffserver` and `ffmpeg` command

[image]

Then you can open your Web Browser and watch the result at : `http://localhost:8090/screen`

Notice that the input for `ffserver` was `/screen.ffm` and the output address was just `/screen` you can change those names accordingly. And here is a screenshot of where it is being played on my local machine:

[image]

Also you can embed the link to a `HTML5` page the watch it on a page:

```
  <video id="screen"  controls> <source src="http://localhost:8090/screen" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support HTML video.
  </video>
```